# Is the land movement effect of Ice Storm subject to SR?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

[Ice Storm](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/iceStorm.htm) has an immediate damaging effect but also a land movement slowing effect that lasts the round.  Is the land movement effect subject to SR as magical or is the slow effect a natural result of the magical hail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the SR-sensitive aspect of a spell is an all-or-none thing: the spell is either SR: Yes, or SR: No. Some spells do have a breakdown of some effects being one and some the other: these are typically listed with a “see text” notation that explains how it works. *Ice storm* is not one of the these spells, and so the fact that it is listed as an SR: Yes spell means that all of its effects are ignored by a resistant creature unless the spell overcomes their SR.

You can think of this as literally ignoring the snow, ice, and water of the *ice storm* spell in their entirety. They are not cold for you, they do not bludgeon you, and they do not make the floor slippery for you.

Answer (score 2):

If a spell caster fails their spell resistance check (also known as a caster level check), a spell has no effect. For all intents and purposes their target is considered as completely immune to that effect until another spell is cast and a spell resistance check is passed.

A spell resistance check is an in game mechanism reflecting a creatures natural resistance to all kinds of magic. Spells most commonly subject to SR are spells of the Evocation school. If you're trying to blast something it's most likely subject to SR, and unless a spell indicates "See Text" passing the check means the creature is immune to all of the spells effects.